# Adding new record with acNewRec and dbs.Execute

Tags: vba, ms-access

I'm stuck on something in MS Access VBA.

I'm trying to add a new record to the table and also adding extra field to a different table.

This is part of the vba code I'm using.

```
'Save the match to the table
DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec

'Step from 1 to the ResultValue
For LCounter = 1 To ResultHomeTeam.Value

Select Case LCounter
    Case 1
        dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO tblMatchPlayer " _
            & "(MatchID, PlayerID, SubstituteID, PositionID, Surname, ScoreTime, RedCards, YellowCards, Substitude, Penalty, OwnGoal, Assist) VALUES " _
            & "(" & Me.MatchID & ", '', '', '', '" & Me.cmScoreName1 & "', " & Me.tbScoreTime1 & ", '', '', '', " & Me.cbPenalty1 & ", " & Me.cbOwnGoal1 & ", '" & Me.cmAssist1 & "');"
```

However this isn't working, if I only use the dbs.Execute it is writing the values to the correct table but then it isn't writing the Match details to the Match Table

I've got it like this

1st part of the form is match details
Date
Opponent
ScoreHomeTeam
ScoreAwayTEam
That should be saved by acNewRec

And the second part of the form are player details who scored
PlayerName
ScoreTime
OwnGoal
Assist

That has to be saved by dbs.execute

No I got two buttons one, to save the match details on it's own and one to save the player details.
But I would like to have one button to save all of it, but when I try to combine acNewRec and dbs.Execute it isn't working.

The problem is I have to save the match details first before I can save the player details cause player details has to have MatchID.

Can anybody help me?

With kind regards,
Patrick

Comment: Your question is very confusing. But to save the current record (and stay on it), use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`, not `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`

Comment: Sorry for the confusing question.
And thanks for the solution I've replaced the line, and now it work. 
Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem part was the first save of the form data.

To save the current record (and stay on it), use `DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord`, not `DoCmd.GoToRecord , , acNewRec`.

The latter does save, but goes to a new, empty record on the form, so you can't use the previously entered values.